# Protect firebird embedded file

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, firebird-embedded

is there any thumb of rules or step-by-step guide how to re-build firebird database in win xp?
I mean to change SYSDBA's password, not with gsec command.. :-D
regard

Answer (score 4):

Changing the password in the firebird embedded server enviroment doesn't make any difference as the [embedded server doesn't authenticate users](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html), it only uses the username. So you can always use the embedded with full privileges using username `SYSDBA` and random password.

Anyway, there is [SQL user management commands](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-security-sql-user-mgmt.html) available in Firebird 2.5 which allow you to work with users without using `gsec`.

Comment: ain - I tried to [rebuild](http://fossies.org/unix/privat/Firebird-2.5.1.26351-0.tar.gz:a/Firebird-2.5.1.26351-0/doc/README.build.msvc.html) with MSVS 2005 to [change SYSDBA](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1933) user, but I couldn't find this root yet, still working. Meanwhile firebird v3 look like [promising](http://www.ibphoenix.fr/IMG/pdf/Firebird_3.pdf). I love to donate firebird, after this superuser resolved. I need it to convince my customers, firebird is best option for their data security and budget. :-D
Pardon for my English, and my best regard for firebird team. :-D

Answer (score 1):

As for today the only way to protect FB embedded database file is to put it onto encrypted disk. Use TrueCrypt or any other available encryption utility.